# java simple switch with enum

Tags: java, enums

I feel like I am just missing something or maybe this is not the use of enum. Pretty much I know I could clean up this code using an enum:

```
    int bookTypeId = 1; //dynamic
    String bookTypeName;
    switch (bookTypeId) {
    case 1:
        bookTypeName = "Fantasy";
        break;
    case 2:
        bookTypeName = "Horror";
        break;
    case 3:
        bookTypeName = "Action";
        break;
    default:
        bookTypeName = "Error";
    }
```

And so I did, I stored it in another class and it looks like:

```
public static enum BookType {
        HORROR("Horror"), FANTASY("Fantasy"), ACTION("Action"), ERROR("Error");

    private String name;

    BookType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Using it now like:

```
switch (bookTypeId) {
    case 1:
        bookTypeName = MYConstants.BookType.FANTASY.getType();
        break;
    case 2:
        bookTypeName = MYConstants.BookType.HORROR.getType();
        break;
    case 3: 
        bookTypeName = MYConstants.BookType.ACTION.getType();
        break;
    default:
        bookTypeName = MYConstants.BookType.ERROR.getType();
    }
```

I want to take this one step further, and clean up my main class of this switch statement (which is sort of why I started looking at enums because right now it seems to do the same thing).

Is it possible to move this switch/case inside of the enum? And then use the enum in a way such as

```
bookTypeName = MYConstants.BookType.getType(bookTypeId);
```

Also is it also possible to declare this enum using final (which it currently is complaining about when I try), or is it already final?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you've put your enum inside `MYConstants`, instead of stand-alone?

Comment: I think a `Class` would work better in this situation.

Comment: @OP you have several answers here; please accept one of them if it answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below?

```
public static enum BookType {

    HORROR(1, "Horror"),
    FANTASY(2, "Fantasy"),
    ACTION(3, "Action");

    private static final Map<Integer, BookType> LOOKUP;

    static {
        LOOKUP = new HashMap<>();
        for (final BookType type : values()) {
            LOOKUP.put(type.id, type);
        }
    }

    public static BookType getById(final int id) {
        final BookType bt = LOOKUP.get(id);
        if (bt == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid book id " + id);
        }
        return bt;
    }

    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    BookType(final int id, final String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
final BookType type = BookType.getById(bookTypeId);
```

You can remove the `String` property and override `toString()`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    final String name = name();
    return name.substring(0, 1) + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

To answer your last question, an `enum` cannot be `final`. `enum` is syntactic sugar; the compiler will desugar it by first creating a `class BookType extends Enum<BookType` and the creating `static final` instances of the new `class` with the specified names. The actual `enum` declaration itself is not *really* a `class` declaration so cannot be `final`. Moreover, if your `enum` constants themselves override or implement methods (like in [this example](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-enum-implementing-an-interface)) then each `enum` constant will be an anonymous class extending `Booktype` - if the `enum` were `final` and that was transposed onto the `BookType` class then this behaviour would not be allowed; and it wouldn't be entirely obvious why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this pattern.

```
public enum BookType {

    INVALID(0),
    HORROR(1),
    FANTASY(2),
    ACTION(3),
    ERROR(4);

    private int value;

    private BookType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString().toLowerCase();
    }

    public static BookType getInstance(int value) {
        for (BookType type : BookType.values()) {
            if (value == type.value) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return INVALID;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BookType b1 = BookType.HORROR;
        System.out.println(b1.toString());

        BookType b2 = BookType.getInstance(3);
        System.out.println(b2.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you need to add an integer field to the enum for this to work?

Comment: Ah, the battle between the Null Object Pattern and throwing exceptions commences...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the significance of the relationship between id and name.  I would try to eliminate the int id all together.  If that isn't possible, consider making it a field in the enum.

```
public static enum BookType {
  HORROR(1, "Horror"), FANTASY(2, "Fantasy"), ACTION(3, "Action"), ERROR(-1, "Error");

  private String name;
  private int typeCode;

  BookType(int typeCode, String name) {
    this.typeCode = typeCode;  
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public int getTypeCode(){
    return typeCode;
  }

  public static BookType getFromTypeCode(int typeCode){
    for(BookType bookType : BookType.values()){
      if(bookType.getTypeCode() == typeCode){
        return bookType;
      }
    }
    return BookType.ERROR;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your switch looks clean enough to me.  If you want to generalize, I wouldn't move hard-coded business logic around to another block of hard-coded business logic.  Push it to a config file or database.  The cleaner approach is a lookup table (of sorts).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are missing something and here it is. This is **all** you need.

```
enum Genre {
    Unknown,
    Fantasy,
    Horror,
    Action,
    Romance;
}
```

You do **not** need to convert the result to and/or from an `int`.

You do **not** need to transform it back and forth to/from a `bookTypeId`, use `valueOf`.

If you need to make a book type be something more than just the `enum` then add attributes to it.

What you are missing is that **the enum itself** can be used elsewhere in you program, it can be saved to database by name and recovered through the `valueOf` method.

Let your `enum` be simple!

Instead of your switch - which seems to be getting a `String` form of the `enum` just do:

```
String name = genre.name();
```

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, enum values really should be written in all caps. Otherwise a good post.

Comment: @ABoschman - That is a hangover from the old C days when it was difficult to tell an important to know what was constant and what wasn't. Java is not C.

Comment: Aw, I've been doing these wrong as well? My professors have some explaining to do.

Comment: Well, if you're right and I'm wrong, at the very least it's a very contested issue. Most of the sources I can find state that they should be all caps, including four of the posters on this page and the oracle docs website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html